# Any alternative to applets, to embed a java 3d game application on webpage?

Tags: javascript, java, html, applet

I want to develop a 3D graphic application which I can embed in a website. I know Java so was thinking about implementing this via applets but since Chrome has withdrawn support from NPAPI plugin which used to support applets. Other browsers support still it but since Chrome has the highest user base, so can't ignore it. Few options I came across are...

1. Java Web Start framework but it opens application in a separate window and downloads the code to client. I'll prefer to have app embed on the page itself.
2. Some suggests entire application development in Javascript + HTML5 but I guess that will make the entire code open via "View Page Source" option.

Is there any alternative to embed a java application on webpage? Please suggest.

Comment: If you're concerned about someone stealing your intellectual property via View > Source, you might consider obfuscating your Javascript. That will prevent casual intruders from claiming your code as their own. Anyone truly dedicated to stealing your game will be able to get it regardless of your security measures.

Comment: That's true...I'm kind of thinking to move towards using javascript now since what's the use of having a game which users can't get to easily. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: *"..and downloads the code to client.."*  That happens with an applet as well. *"..but it opens application in a separate window.."*  I don't see that as a disadvantage unless the app. needs to communicate back and forth with the web page via Javascript.  Why do you see it as a *benefit* to have the app. embedded in a web page?

Comment: I was told entire code doesn't get copied to the client machine when using an applet.... I want the app embedded in webpage bcz i want the web activities to be visible to the client at the time he's working with the applet. Separate window makes it a bad experience.

Comment: *"I was told entire code doesn't get copied to the client machine when using an applet...."*  Only if 1) it is deployed using JWS. 2) Jars have been marked as lazy loadable. 3) the user has not yet used that area of functionality.  But it is trivial for a thief to pull the JNLP into a text area in an option pane, then do a direct fetch on each of the jars.  That brings me back to *"..people who need to ask these kinds of questions.."* & that you are obviously a naive newbie to this whole area of enterprise..

Comment: If your points are correct then maybe I was given incomplete information before which is why I'am thankful to you for making it full. Will do some reading on that. Of course I am new to this area of development, otherwise I wouldn't have asked this question. Thanks for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, no, there is not. The browsers are abandoning Java due to its lack of security. Moreover, a Java plug-in is also required. Nowadays, you really should take advantage of the Javascript + HTML5 features. While Java loses its support day after day, the contrary happens with HTML5.

Comment: but isn't it javascript code go completely open and anyone can view it, download it & do whatever they want with it once you go live. Isn't it losing credibility of the code you've written in months or years?? :(

There should be an alternative to this. not talking about obfuscating. Anything we can do with java? Anyone??

Comment: I see your point, buddy, but it is what it is. The current recommendation is to get rid of Java, Flash and so on and use Javascript + HTML5 + CSS3...

Comment: Java can be pretty trivially decompiled; if you are publishing Java code, it's really not much different than obfuscated JS. Licensing is a more effective way to prevent someone from re-using your code than obfuscation.

Comment: @smorgan Licencing might not stop them from copying part of the code I guess...Can we do both? Is that possible to obfuscate a licensed code?

OR like disabling the right click or removing the option of view source from right click options?

Comment: *"Licencing might not stop them from copying part of the code I guess..."*  ***Nothing*** will stop people from stealing an app. if it goes online (and is worth stealing).  But usually people who need to ask these kinds of questions about their 'one man project' do not write apps. worth stealing.  Don't get me wrong, the thief  might steal a great idea.  But they would want to implement that idea using their own programmers. Protect your product by issuing constant updates and improvements, and offer paid support.

Comment: @AndrewThompson thank you for the vote of confidence..It doesn't matter if the app is One man project or not if you or your team has put in efforts to implement a good idea, you'd certainly want to keep it from being stolen, copied or at least make it hard for others. They can take the idea all they want but why make it easy for them to implement it simply by copying the code? I asked the question to find if there's a way to accomplish both objectives. Wondering why people who stress much on security don't design technology that should hide or obfuscate the code by default when it goes online.

Comment: *"..implement a good idea, you'd certainly want to keep it from being stolen,"*  The thing you seem to be missing though, is that a 'good idea' is not easy to copyright.  Code can be copyright, an invention can be patented, but there is little space in between to make a proprietary claim on a 'good idea'. *"why make it easy for them to implement it simply by copying the code?"*  A 'good idea' would usually be obvious by using the program.  No need (at all) to go into the code.  And even if it WAS easier to go into the code, they'd want it rewritten by some rigorous methodology.  Stop dreaming.

Comment: _"No need (at all) to go into the code."_ ...You're missing the point, No need is fine but wouldn't it be better if it was "There's NO OPTION to go in the code". Best for everyone.

Comment: There's nothing to stop you from obfuscating code and still having a license on it, if you think obfuscating is helpful. Neither obfuscating JS, nor using compiled Java, is the same as making it impossible for someone dedicated to get (hard-to-read) code.